# how do I make axios API call in a separate component / file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do I make axios API call in a separate component / file?

example:

I created the index.jsx file that contains the component to integrate `axios` and after that I created the `app.jsx` file to render the index.jsx file containing axios in the `index.jsx` file

thanks before

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Hi @nadzief. Welome to SO. Suggest you to add code snippet with people when asking for help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can use redux with react for this.

Comment: @Nadzief Do you know how to use import/export in general? How to call a function from a different file? If not, read up on that.

Answer (score 21):

You can create a separate folder `api` for all APIs:

Let's say you have `AuthenticationAPI`, you have to something like this:

AuthenticationAPI.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const onAuthenticate = payload => {
  const URL = `YOUR_URL`;
  return axios(URL, {
    method: 'POST/GET',
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json', // whatever you want
    },
    data: payload,
  })
    .then(response => response.data)
    .catch(error => {
      throw error;
    });
};
```

in you App.js

```
import * as AuthenticateAPI from 'api/AuthenticationAPI';

 // in your CDM
 componentDidMount(){
  AuthenticateAPI.onAuthenticate(payload).then((res)=>{ //any payload you want to send just for example
    you can get response here in then block
 }) 
 }
```

This is for the sake of basic example. You can use redux if it becomes the **NECESSITY**
Otherwise **don't abuse it**.

PS: **Axios** is built on cancellable promise pattern. It has it's abort controller. In short you can cancel any pending network call which is an great alternative to use Observable. Cancel API calls is really important sometimes when you don't really need the data while navigation to another page in between ongoing API request so the data is useless and AXIOS is the lone savior.

Comment: Awesome solution. Can you show how we can your code along with cancellation implementation so when new request comes older pending request cancelled

Comment: How to add a spinner in common file ? Like changing the state true/false

Answer (score 8):

You can import `functions` / `methods` on the fly using `export`

Create a shared.js file. for example call it: apicalls.js

inside write your functions as so:

**apicalls.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';

export function getData(config, callback, errorcallback){
    axios.get(url, config)
    .then(res => {
      //do something
      if(callback != null){
         callback(res);
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      // catch error
      if(errorcallback != null){
         errorcallback(err);
      }
    })
}
```

**In any component, use as follows**

```
// get the location of your apicalls.js file and use to import like below
import { getData } from '../../routetothisjsfile'


//use it 
var config = { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" }
getData(config, (res) => {
    //success
},(err) => {
    //error
    alert(err);
});
```